# disabling AF programmatically?

Tags: c#, focus, edsdk, canon-sdk

I have a EOS 1100D and use edsdk to taking picture by my camera from my computer.
in Manual mode I should can chand every properties, and in *EOS Utility*  that is released by Canon, in Manual mode, user can switch between AF and MF. So, there should be a property!

What I found in EDSDK.cs is:

```
    /*---------------------------------------------
     Focus Info
    ----------------------------------------------*/
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct EdsFocusPoint
    {
        public uint valid;
        public uint selected;
        public uint justFocus;
        public EdsRect rect;
        public uint reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct EdsFocusInfo
    {
        public EdsRect imageRect;
        public uint pointNumber;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
        public EdsFocusPoint[] focusPoint;
        public uint executeMode;
    }
```

How can I set this `executeMode`?
In fact, I should set in to what for AF and what for MF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with EdsSendCommand where inCommand is kEdsCameraCommand_PressShutterButton and inParam is one of the kEdsCameraCommand_ShutterButton_ values.
With it you can control the shutterbutton (i.e. press it remotely).
To take a photo without AF, you simply use the value CameraCommand_ShutterButton_Completely_NonAF
But don't forget to set it back to CameraCommand_ShutterButton_OFF after you have taken the photo!
In the EDSDK documentation you can find details on page 42 and 43.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Johannes. I downloaded *EDSDK Documatation* and in that part you mensioned, in Discription field, it says: **Controls shutter button operations. 
This command is supproted by the EOS 
50D or EOS 5D Mark II or later cameras.** As I said, my camera is an EOS 1100D. So, it seems that this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @ayssa yes it does work for the 1100D. Later is meant as in released later. The 50D was released in 2008 and the 1100D in 2011. just try it out and you'll see.